# react-native unable to capture coordinates of touch event

Tags: react-native

I am trying to capture the x, y coordinates of a touch event. I would like that given any touch event on the screen I can capture the x, y coordinates of the touch.

I am using TouchableOpacity and can respond to onPress, but it does not get passed coordinates.

Comment: Solved: A little more exploring and I found that onPress receives an event parameter "event.nativeEvent.locationX" and "event.nativeEvent.locationY"

Comment: I did not get it your solution "event.nativeEvent.locationX" and "event.nativeEvent.locationY

Answer (score 0):

When a touchable fires the `onPress` handler, an event variable is passed in to the handler. You can extract the coordinates from the event as follows:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={(event) => {
        const {
            // Location (x,y) is relative to
            // the top-left of the component
            locationX,
            locationY,

            // Page (x,y) is relative to
            // the top-left of the device screen
            pageX,
            pageY,
        } = event.nativeEvent
    }
}
```